# Botframework - Proactive - UnauthorizedAccessException on cold call

Tags: botframework

I have a custom WebApi controller hosted next to my normal bot MessagesController. This custom Controller gets call so often to perform proactive messaging to users for sending out notifications.

```
public bool Post([FromBody]SchedulerTrigger triggerInfo)
{
    try
    {                                                            
        //Initiate background processing of notifications
        Task.Run(() => NotificationTask.NotificationProcessing(triggerInfo));

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw ex;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The controller does not have the [BotAuthentication] attribute and should not since it is being called from elsewhere.

The NotificationProcessing function does some crunching but in the end it calls a Dialog:

```
public static async Task Resume(string resumptionCookie)
{
        //Deserialize reference to conversation
        ConversationReference conversationReference = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConversationReference>(resumptionCookie);

        using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message))
        {
            var botData = scope.Resolve<IBotData>();

            await botData.LoadAsync(CancellationToken.None);

            //This is our dialog stack
            var task = scope.Resolve<IDialogTask>();

            //interrupt the stack. This means that we're stopping whatever conversation that is currently happening with the user
            //Then adding this stack to run and once it's finished, we will be back to the original conversation
            var dialog = new MyProActiveDialog();

            try
            {
                task.Call(dialog.Void<object, IMessageActivity>(), null);
                await task.PollAsync(CancellationToken.None);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //TODO
            }
            finally
            {
                //flush dialog stack
                await botData.FlushAsync(CancellationToken.None);
            }

        }
}
```

All works well when the Web Service is up and running and has at least performed once login with https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token after any type of chit chat between microsoft bot and my webservice.

However, if I restart my webservice and kick-off the pro-active discussion I get UnauthorizedAccessException.

I tried to perform manual authentication with BotAuthenticator or adding [BotAuthentication] with a passed token but I always endup with  UnauthorizedAccessException.

So I noticed that the Beerer is only present on a none cold start. I found no way to force authentication on cold start... 
[Image of Fiddler Web Service --> To Bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UmdP.jpg)

Any type of help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered this error before.  Essentially, the channel that the message is coming from is "trusted".  The workaround is to trust that channel access.

Try this (first parameter should be the service url):

```
MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(@"https://skype.botframework.com", DateTime.MaxValue);
```